# How set up the screen that I see in my user flow AZ AD B2C

Tags: angular, azure, authentication, azure-active-directory

I've successfully integrated B2C authentication in my angular app using the MSAL package following this tutorial:

[Configure authentication in a sample Angular...](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/configure-authentication-sample-angular-spa-app) until step 3.

The "problem" comes when the authority has to be set like this: https:// login.microsoftonline.com/common as it says [here](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/blob/dev/lib/msal-node/docs/initialize-confidential-client-application.md) instead of this https://your-tenant-name.b2clogin.com/your-tenant-name.onmicrosoft.com/b2c_1_susi_reset_v2

And setting the authority domain as common or using my tenant id I can only see this screens
Common:
[image]

using tenant id:
And when I click the use another account -> sign in options only see github and signIn with a key
[image]

When the screen that I would like to see is this one (due to the identity providers):
[image]

Am I missing some link or a configuration in my AD?

**SOLUTION:**

as Greg told me, if you want to see the screen that displays as user flow in azure (last pic) you need to create custom policies:

[Create user flows and custom policies in Azure Active Directory B2C](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/tutorial-create-user-flows?pivots=b2c-custom-policy#get-the-starter-pack)

Create the two more apps and get the starter pack and configure with your own tenant name as the link says.

[if you want to add more social providers](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/tree/main/articles/active-directory-b2c)

In my case when trying to upload the xml's there was an error and this very helpful tool helped me (you can overwrite the files that it creates)
[Quick deploy samples](https://b2ciefsetupapp.azurewebsites.net/Home/Experimental)

And finally in the authority field that requires the SMAL config you set 'https://your-tenant-name.b2clogin.com/your-tenant-name.onmicrosoft.com/b2c_1_YOUR_CUSTOM_POLICY_NAME'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check how to customize interface with **User Flows/Custom Policies**.
Not only you can customize  existing user experience (login screen, password reset, etc) but you may create your own "journeys" with **Custom Policies**.

You deploy those customization to your Azure AD B2C tenant , not in your app.
Here is [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/customize-ui-with-html?pivots=b2c-custom-policy)

Comment: It was a little bit confusing and chaotic but finally am able to see the screen that I want, I'll edit my question.